# Custom authentication for Blazer (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where do I define `authenticate!` to get custom authentication for [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer)?

I have this (uncommented) line in my `config/blazer.yml` (as described in the README under [Authentication > Other](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#other)):

```
before_action: :authenticate!
```

When I refresh my app, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at / undefined method 'authenticate!' for #<Blazer::QueriesController:0x007ffe26447830>
```

That class is defined by the Blazer gem. Am I supposed to add/redefine its `authenticate!` method somehow?

I tried adding an `initializers/blazer.rb` file where I defined:

```
class Blazer::QueriesController < Blazer::BaseController
  def authenticate!
    true
  end
end
```

But now, when I click "New Query" in Blazer, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Blazer::Queries#new undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

Rails 4.2.5, Blazer 1.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your custom method into `application_controller.rb`. You then put the name of the method into `config/blazer.yml` to wire it up.

I would recommend using `Devise` for authentication. The Devise wiki has a great starting article [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers). The engine and routes of blazer must also be protected as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/ankane/blazer#devise).

Comment: Thanks, `application_controller` is correct. Your final two sentences might confuse people, though, as the Blazer wiki has different instructions if authenticating via Devise, see: https://github.com/ankane/blazer#devise . If you remove or modify your Devise your comment, I'll accept the asnwer. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to include the route protection from the readme.